# How to add a custom expect-chain element?

Tags: nightwatch.js

Specifically: I'd like to insert a "removeWhitespace" in a

```js
expect.element('...').text.to.equal('...')
```

chain. Thus it will look like this:

```js
expect.element('...').text.removeWhitespace.to.equal(...)
```

Reason: I don't want to care about any amount and type of whitespace in the assertion, I just want to compare letters.

More general: I'd like to add a custom element to an expect-chain in order to manipulate the data that I'm handling in the assertion. Or in other words: I'd like to define and register my own expect-chain elements like possible with custom assertions. How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

But you don't need to add a custom expect add a function to wrap the string like this:

```
expect.element(removeWhiteSpaces('...')).text.to.equal('...')

function removeWhiteSpaces(string){
     return string.trim();
}
```

you can use whatever function you want it's javascript! you are free.
So parse the string first.

But if you need to add a custom assertion go to the nightwatch guide [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-assertions)

Comment: Well, that's removing whitespace from the element's identifier (something like "  @myElement  "), but not from the HTML content of the element itself. The example above said: "Get the content (i.e. "text") of an element, strip all whitespace and compare it to something [,,,] to be equal."

Comment: Adding custom assertions is quite clear, but I don't want to use the assert... pattern, I want to use the expect... pattern. afaik they cannot be mixed up in one line, can they?